# java.net.UnknownHostException when accessing a URL

Tags: java, urlconnection

Below code :

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");   
URLConnection inputStream =oracle.openConnection();
InputStream in = inputStream.getInputStream();
```

Throws this exception :

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.oracle.com
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:234)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
```

I think this exception is thrown because the proxy server is blocking my connection? I just want to parse some data from the URL, can I accomplish this without running into the firewall ?

Comment: Can you access http://www.oracle.com in your browser?

Comment: If you could evade a firewall that easily, there wouldn't really be a point to it. If you think it's your firewall, is turning it off for a second an option?

Comment: Yes, www.oracle.com is accessible from my browser

Comment: Accessing the url in a browser is a good check too but would only mean something if that browser isn't using the proxy he mentioned.

Comment: I don't have the permissions to turn it off, even temporarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a proxy server, please make sure that you are setting the appropriate system properties.
See the Oracle page at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html for details.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to include the below line in your manifest. It should be a direct child of manifest node.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```