# Can MULE post XML-file over HTTP from local directory?

Tags: http, post, mule

I need to transfer XML-files over HTTP POST. Can Mule be configured to do this. I've been trying with an easy flow, inbound file --> outound HTTP but it's not working. Does anyone have any experience of this?

```
    <flow name="rpg_uploadFlow1" doc:name="rpg_uploadFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Claes\Documents\CD-utveckling\paper-rpg\OUT" moveToDirectory="C:\Users\Claes\Documents\CD-utveckling\paper-rpg\sent" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="File"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="http://XXXXXXXXXXX.ashx?SystemName=XXXX&amp;UserName=XXXX&amp;PassWord=XXXXX" port="80" disableTransportTransformer="true" doc:name="HTTP"/>

</flow>
```

Error;

```
ERROR 2013-05-17 17:24:49,208 [[rpg_upload].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.07]    org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
```

---

```
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint:   DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/rpgtest/service.ashx?  SystemName=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&UserName=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&PassWord=xxxxxxx,  connector=HttpConnector
{
   name=connector.http.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=18b44ce0
   numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
   createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
   connected=true
   supportedProtocols=[http]
   serviceOverrides=<none>
 }
 ,       name='endpoint.http.http.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service.ashx.SystemName.xxxxx.UserName.xxxxx.Pass       Word.836749.80', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={PassWord=836749:80, SystemName=xxxxxx,      UserName=xxxxxxxxx}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=true}. Message payload is of type: ReceiverFileInputStream
    Code                  : MULE_ERROR-42999
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Exception stack is:
 1. http (java.net.UnknownHostException)
  java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl:-1 (null)
 2. Failed to route event via endpoint:   DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://http://xxxxxxxxxx.ashx?   SystemName=xxxxxxxxxxxx&UserName=xxxxxx&PassWord=836749:80, connector=HttpConnector
 {
   name=connector.http.mule.default
   lifecycle=start
   this=18b44ce0       
   numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
   connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[http]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
      }
    ,        name='endpoint.http.http.xxxx.ashx.SystemName.xxxxxxxx.UserName.xxxxx.PassWord.836749.80',     mep=ONE_WAY, properties={PassWord=836749:80, SystemName=xxxxxxxxxx, UserName=xxxx},    transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0},    deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000,    endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=true}. Message payload is of type:    ReceiverFileInputStream (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
       org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher:155    (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchExceptio n.html)
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Root Exception stack trace:
      java.net.UnknownHostException: http
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

---

Comment: can you post your config?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes, now I've posted the flow. I thought that the file indound endpoint would get the file to the payload and then the outbound endpoint would post it?

Comment: Post the error you get when you try this.

Comment: Now is also the error message posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had trouble in some spots with the file endpoint because it passes along a filereader as the payload instead of the actual text. Try adding a file-to-string converter:

```
<flow name="rpg_uploadFlow1" doc:name="rpg_uploadFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Claes\Documents\CD-utveckling\paper-rpg\OUT" moveToDirectory="C:\Users\Claes\Documents\CD-utveckling\paper-rpg\sent" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="http://XXXXXXXXXXX.ashx?SystemName=XXXX&amp;UserName=XXXX&amp;PassWord=XXXXX" port="80" disableTransportTransformer="true" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the magic! file:file-to-string-transformer was what i needed. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mule byte array to string transformer to make your request as string and then post it to your http outbound.

```
<flow name="rpg_uploadFlow1" doc:name="rpg_uploadFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Claes\Documents\CD-utveckling\paper-rpg\OUT" moveToDirectory="C:\Users\Claes\Documents\CD-utveckling\paper-rpg\sent" responseTimeout="10000" mimeType="text/xml" doc:name="File"/>

    <byte-array-to-string-transformer></byte-array-to-string-transformer>
  .....
```

Coming to your error. I gues it is not related to mule tags and endpoints. It is something in accessing the url you are trying.

See the below post for the issue related to UnknownHostException.

[java.net.UnknownHostException when accessing a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909280/java-net-unknownhostexception-when-accessing-a-url)

Comment: I think the error came from that I've written http:// in front of the url which makes double http: in the call. Thanx! /CLaes

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
You can use a mule byte array to string transformer to make your requested File as string and then use SetPayload or Attachment Connector and post it to your http outbound.